# saving image files in django model

Tags: django

i want to store a lot of images in a table(model of django) under an attribute 'imgsrc'. How do i do that? i have seen a lot of online material but i am not getting the complete information anywhere. What changes do i need to do in settings.py and where do i store my image files?...

a part of models.py

```
class elementdetails(models.Model):
    sid=models.IntegerField()
    imgsrc=models.ImageField()
    soundsrc=models.FileField()
    sounddesc=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: please post your views and the template with the form.

Answer (score 4):

Setup `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in you `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your `urls.py`, add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Make sure to have `media` directory in your root directory.

Now, you can also use `uploaded_to` in your model for storing those `images` in a directory.

```
class elementdetails(models.Model):
    sid=models.IntegerField()
    imgsrc=models.ImageField(upload_to='elements/')
    soundsrc=models.FileField()
    sounddesc=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In order to get the image in `templates`, use:

```
<img src="{{ object.imgsrc.url }}" alt="image">
```

If you want to upload images in forms, make sure to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `template`:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, make sure in `views`, use:

```
form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

It will work.

Comment: if i have the following structure: mysite/myapp/   then the urls.py above is of myapp right? and also the media directory is made where? in mysite or myapp?

Comment: yes, `urls.py` in your `myapp`, and `media` directory inside `mysite` directory.

Comment: It's Okay, not a problem at all. Try it now, it will work.

Comment: i have made a directory mysite/media...but i have written upload_to='elements/'...what is elements here and where will it be made?

Comment: OK, so `media` directory will be where all your media files will be stored. We might have different model with `ImageField`, so it is a good practice to store each model `images` in different directory inside `media`. Thus, if you upload any Image in this model, it will me stored in `media/elements/filename.png`, where `filename.png` is your uploaded image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154547/discussion-between-piyush-maurya-and-shefali).